# Using BehaviorSubject<boolean> vs. a plain boolean property in angular

Tags: angular, rxjs

Suppose an HTML element using angular code like

```
<div *ngIf="(stateX$ | async)" ...
```

where `stateX$` is an rxjs `BehaviorSubject<boolean>` and the angular component's code contains

```
this.stateX$.next(...)
```

after some unwieldy computation. Could we equally well define `stateX` as just a `boolean` and use

```
<div *ngIf="stateX" ...
```

and respectively in the component code

```
this.stateX = ...
```

assuming that angular will pick up the change of `stateX` in the same way as it should note a new value in the `BehaviorSubject`? If either way works, what are the benefits/shortcomings of the two solutions?

Comment: I think having Subject only to set boolean flag used in view is just complication of the code.

Answer (score 4):

## Performance.

Angular's change detection is fairly quick, but on larger dynamic apps it can quickly start to eat up a lot of time. Angular needs to loop through every variable in every component and check for changes.

`stateX$ | async` doesn't need angular's change detection (as such). This approach tells angular what is being changed, where it is being changed, and when it is being changed. A program that lean heavily into this approach can remove angular's change detection entirely!

Doing this for a smaller app will create such small benefits that the added complexity is likely not worth it. For larger apps, however, this benefit alone can make the endeavor worth it.

## Design.

Observables are future-proofing your design because they're a solution to a very old and pervasive problem in front-end development

Web-design has always been rife with inversion of control. In it's youth, most javascript involved setting up subscriptions to various DOM events and letting the browser run your code appropriately.

Nowadays JS is written that **"reacts"** to events from the DOM, from servers, from internal services, the list goes on. Large portions of the code you write is controlled by some other system you have no direct control over.

The upside is that you're not in control of these external systems and therefore do not need to manage them. For example: Websites don't need JS to render the DOM, browsers handle all that for you. I can create a website without a single line of JS.

The downside is the same, it's hard to control the order/frequency/etc that external services will call your code. Traditionally, this has lead to callback hell. Promise and Observables have both addressed this major downside to various degrees.

Making this reactive-style code much cleaner to write/manage.

---

Angular change detection leaves this control in the hands of the caller a little longer. The benefit is that changing a variable remains a very simple one-liner. The downside is that the entire system doesn't interoperate with the rest of the way front-side development works.

*Imagine this:* A boolean value that is read/updated by a whole host of components becomes important to a component is a new way. This new component wants to keep a count of every time this value is set true and every time this value is set false. The state of this component is tied to the change of of a value in some way.

**With RxJS**, values are no different from server responses or DOM events. They're just events you can hook into. Writing this code is simple.

**Without RxJS**, this becomes complex. You can add some code that gets called in every location that you update this boolean, then just pray that future maintainers remember to do this too (Error-prone). You can turn it into a "service" with getters and setters and a way to hook into these changes, but suddenly you're writting something more complex than an observable that doesn't have the same performance/extensability of this battle-tested library. Why bother?

---

In the end, you can manage the complexity of large system by unifying the abstractions you use wherever possible. If you're going to be using RxJS elsewhere anyway, why not just drop Angular Change Detection entirely and go whole-hog? Sure, updating a boolean becomes a bit less ergonomic, but everything across you're entire application will be dealt with using the same data-flow.

Answer (score 3):

You are correct that both `boolean` and `BehaviorSubject<boolean>` would give the same results as you described in your example.

The reason the template view updates when you change a `boolean` property is due to Angular's default change detection system. In simple examples like the one you described, using basic properties is the better/easier option.

The reason to use `BehaviorSubject` along with other tools within RxJS is when you want to setup a reactive data flow for your app's state management. I would recommend watching some conference keynotes from Deborah Kurata as a good starting point for learning this reactive data flow, and its benefits.

Using RxJS also opens the opportunity to use Angular's optional change detection strategy, one that requires far less overhead.

I would also recommend this article covering Angular's change detection and its relationship with RxJS: https://medium.com/swlh/amazingly-simplified-angular-change-detection-explanation-feef61b85573

Comment: In the case I am looking for it is really as simple as the example, `BehaviorSubject` might actually be overkill. And thanks for the pointers, I'll take a closer look.